# Multiple Blanks in ReplaceAll not regarded as different Patterns?

Tags: replacement

I'm having trouble with a simple replacement-rule. It seems my understanding of Blanks is wrong. I have an expression containing the following multiple times:

`e[a1,a2] e[b1,b2] e[c1,c2]`

I want to replace this expression with zero, whenever `a2=b2=c2`. The following replacement-rule however does nothing to the expression:

`e[a1,1] e[b1,1] e[c1,1]/.e[_,a_] e[_,a_] e[_,a_]->0`,

whereas the following works:

`e[a1,1] e[b1,1] e[c1,1]/.e[_,a_] e[d_,a_] e[f_,a_]->0`

I don't really understand why. I know that `d_`has the `Head` `Pattern`, which is why it is colored green in the rule, whereas `_` has the `Head` `Blank` and is left in black. But that doesn't really help me.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at what `e[_, a_] e[_, a_] e[_, a_] -> 0` evaluates to.  Then use `HoldPattern[e[_, a_] e[_, a_] e[_, a_]] -> 0` to prevent that evaluation.

Comment: Or, `e[a1, 1] e[b1, 1] e[c1, 1] /. Repeated[e[_, a_]] e[_, a_] -> 0`

Comment: @jjc385  Thank you! I didn't consider that